# Duplicar input y que se pueda modificar y eliminar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy tratando de dar la posibilidad de que puedan ingresar varias fechas en un mismo registro duplicando el campo pero hay algo que no me esta saliendo.

```js
var adj_actual = 1;

function add() {
    var nuevo = $('#itemDate').clone();
    nuevo.attr('id', '');
    var adj_nuevo = adj_actual + 1;
    nuevo.find('input').each(function() {
        this.value = '';
        this.name = this.name.replace(1, adj_nuevo);
    });
    adj_actual = adj_nuevo;
    $('#itemDate').append(nuevo);
}

function removeThisFile(ele) {
    $(ele).parents('.itemDate').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4" id="itemDate">
    <x-fielddate label='Fecha' name='date' :data='$data' placeholder='Fecha' />
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    <p class="text-right" style="padding-top: 1.5rem">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="add();">
            <i class="mi-add"></i>
            Agregar
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas por corregir en tu código:

1. Para facilitar el mantenimiento de tus proyectos no asignes eventos en línea `onclick="funcion"`, mejor "escucha": `$(elemento)on.(evento, funcion);`
2. No uses nombres del tipo `date1`, es mejor usar corchetes para que sean tratados como un arreglo `date[]`; al final del fragmento de código agregué un ejemplo para obtenerlos y recorrerlos
3. Estás agregando el elemento clonado dentro del mismo contenedor, la primera vez que haces clic en "Agregar" parece funcionar bien, pero la segunda, te crea dos nuevos campos. Necesitas que el nuevo elemento quede fuera y antes del botón, por lo que se recomienda usar [.insertBefore()](https://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)
4. Al clonar, agrega también un botón y escucha los clics para eliminar
5. El método `.parents()` no es el más adecuado para obtener el contenedor padre, porque puede haber varios niveles. Es mejor usar [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) especificando el selector que, en este caso, es la clase `itemDate`

```js
function add(){
    // Clonar contenedor, eliminar ID
    let nuevo = $('#itemDate').clone();
    nuevo.attr('id', '');
    // Agregar clase para poder obtener el padre al eliminar
    nuevo.addClass('itemDate');
    nuevo.find('input').each(function() {
        // Solo establecer el valor
        this.value = '';
        // Dejar el nombre con corchetes, para que sea un arreglo
    });
    // Agregar botón para eliminar
    $(nuevo).append(' <button class="item-delete">X</button>');
    // Insertar nuevo contenedor antes del botón "Agregar"
    $(nuevo).insertBefore('#item-add');
}
// Función para eliminar
function removeThisFile(ele) {
    // $(this) es el elemento que disparó el evento
    // ele no es el elemento, sino el evento
    // Obtener padre por clase, usando closest()
    $(this).closest('.itemDate').remove();
}
// Escuchar clic en botón Agregar
$('#item-add .button').on('click', add);

// Escuchar clic en botones para borrar
$(document.body).on('click', '.item-delete', removeThisFile);

// Solo para probar
$('#item-check button').on('click', function() {
    // Recorrer todos los campos
    // Todos tienen el mismo nombre, pero cada uno tiene índice
    $('[name="date[]"]').each(function(index) {
        console.log(index, $(this)[0]);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="itemDate">
            <label><input type="date" name="date[]" placeholder='Fecha'></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2" id="item-add">
            <p class="text-right" style="padding-top: 1.5rem">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="add();">
                    <i class="mi-add"></i>
                    Agregar
                </button>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Esto es solo para probar -->
        <div class="col-md-2" id="item-check">
            <p class="text-right" style="padding-top: 1.5rem">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
                   Obtener campos
                </button>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: perfecto, voy a poner en practica eso, muchas gracias por su colaboración..!!